# Tramp+bookmark crash when setting a different tramp-persistency-file-name file location

Tags: tramp, bookmarks

I have set `tramp-persistency-file-name` to a custom location since I want all the files generated by emacs stored in a specific location.

```
(setq files-dir "~/src/emacs.d/vendor/files/")
(setq custom-file (concat files-dir "custom.el")
      tramp-persistency-file-name (concat files-dir "tramp")
      host-file (concat hosts-dir (replace-regexp-in-string "[^A-Za-z0-9_-]" "-" (downcase (car (split-string (system-name) "\\.")))) ".el")
      version-file (concat versions-dir (number-to-string emacs-major-version) ".el"))
```

I do have some bookmarks set to some remote locations, that are supposed to use tramp to reach some remote files.

So, the "first time" I use it, it works. I can reach my `/scp:host:/path` remote path and open some files.

Then, Tramp generates the history file in the right location I've set (`~/src/emacs.d/vendor/files/tramp`).

But the next time, I want to open such a location, it crashes and generates this backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (["scp" nil "my-host" nil nil] ("locale" "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8") ("uname" "Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64") ("test" "test") ("remote-path" ("/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin")) ("remote-shell" "/bin/sh") ("stat" "\\stat") ("file-exists" "test -e") ("id" "/usr/bin/id") ("gid-string" "my-user") ("ls" "/bin/ls --color=never") ("ls-dired" t) ("gid-integer" 1016) ("perl-file-spec" t) ("perl-cwd-realpath" t) ("perl" "\\perl") ("readlink" "\\readlink")))
  ((["scp" nil "my-host" nil nil] ("locale" "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8") ("uname" "Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64") ("test" "test") ("remote-path" ("/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin")) ("remote-shell" "/bin/sh") ("stat" "\\stat") ("file-exists" "test -e") ("id" "/usr/bin/id") ("gid-string" "my-user") ("ls" "/bin/ls --color=never") ("ls-dired" t) ("gid-integer" 1016) ("perl-file-spec" t) ("perl-cwd-realpath" t) ("perl" "\\perl") ("readlink" "\\readlink")))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/my-user/src/emacs.d/vendor/files/tramp" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 702
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/my-user/src/emacs.d/vendor/files/tramp" "/Users/my-user/src/emacs.d/vendor/files/tramp" nil t)
  load("tramp" nil t)
  (let ((default-directory (or (symbol-value (quote temporary-file-directory)) "/"))) (load "tramp" nil t))
  tramp-autoload-file-name-handler(expand-file-name "/scp:my-host:/home/my-user/my/path" nil)
  file-readable-p("/scp:my-host:/home/my-user/my/path")
  bookmark-default-handler(("MyBookmark" (filename . "/scp:my-host:/home/my-user/my/path")))
  byte-code("\301!\206�\302\303!!\207" [bookmark-name-or-record bookmark-get-handler bookmark-default-handler bookmark-get-bookmark] 3)
  bookmark-handle-bookmark("MyBookmark")
  bookmark--jump-via("MyBookmark" switch-to-buffer)
  bookmark-jump("MyBookmark")
  bookmark-bmenu-this-window()
  call-interactively(bookmark-bmenu-this-window nil nil)
  command-execute(bookmark-bmenu-this-window)
```

Note: if I comment the line `setq tramp-persistency-file-name blabla`, it solves the problem but the file is located in my `emacs.d` directory (which I do not want).

Do you have any idea what's going wrong ?
Should I report a bug or am I the bug ?

**EDIT**: as requested here is the `tramp` file generated after the first use of the feature

```
;; -*- emacs-lisp -*- <15/12/23 10:35:22 ~/src/emacs.d/vendor/files/tramp>
;; Tramp connection history.  Don't change this file.
;; You can delete it, forcing Tramp to reapply the checks.

((["scp" nil "my-host" nil nil]
  ("locale" "LC_ALL=en_US.utf8")
  ("uname" "Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64")
  ("test" "test")
  ("remote-path"
   ("/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin"))
  ("remote-shell" "/bin/sh")
  ("stat" "\\stat")
  ("file-exists" "test -e")
  ("id" "/usr/bin/id")
  ("gid-string" "my-user")
  ("ls" "/bin/ls --color=never")
  ("ls-dired" t)
  ("gid-integer" 1016)
  ("readlink" "\\readlink")
  ("perl-file-spec" t)
  ("perl-cwd-realpath" t)
  ("perl" "\\perl")))
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/Users/my-user/src/emacs.d/vendor/files/tramp` (be careful to remove personal info)? Looks like something is wrong with that file.

Comment: Done. But it is generated by tramp, I did not edit it. Thanks for your time anyways

Comment: Well, the thing is: Emacs is trying to load this file, but loading it means interpreting it as Lisp code, and as such, it is not valid `["scp" ...]` is not a function. Does this file look the same if you don't modify the path? (perhaps there's a `'` before the first paren, or maybe even more code preceding it?).

Comment: Just tried. It does look the same. begins by `((["scp" nil "my-host" nil nil]` . Anyway, why would it change the content file by changing its location ? Is there any reason ?

Comment: From looking at `tramp-autoload-file-name-handler` there doesn't seem to be any reason for this file to look this way. It just looks like the contents of this file were meant for something else... I'd write to Emacs mailing list to ask why it looks the way it does. On the surface of it, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You might want to also show the Lisp content of the bookmark in question. You can find that in your bookmark file. And if it turns out that the bookmark is not important to reproduce the problem then you can remove mention of it from your description. That will help others with a similar problem find this question, and avoid people finding it when looking for bookmark questions.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Tramp error. I have tried the following test: `emacs -Q --eval '(setq tramp-persistency-file-name "/tmp/tramp")'` Calling it several times, and opening remote files in this Emacs session, works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand. Your `files-dir` is contained in `load-path`. When Tramp is loaded, Emacs finds the  file `tramp` in this directory and tries to load it instead of `tramp.el` in its original directory.

Give that file another name but `tramp` or `tramp.el`, or locate it in another directory, which is not covered by `load-path`.

Comment: Michael, you are my hero.